# Intercept back Button to Go back in webView if pressed once and exit if pressed twice

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, android-studio, webview

I am using WebView to view my offline webpage which contains few html pages named 1.html, 2.html and so on with main page index.html.It has only one Mainactivity and for now I'm using below code to exit the app when pressed twice. I want to add functionality to go back to previous page if pressed once and exit the app when pressed twice.
Here is the code for now which exit the app if pressed twice

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
super.onBackPressed();
return;
}

this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
}
}, 2000);
}
```

Any help would be much much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Im not so sure its a good pattern because it would be confusing to the user, if you want double back to exit the activity, and a single back to go to the previous page, you should consider adding a back button to activity title where users would have a dedicated back button. Notwithstanding though, what you can do in this case is go to the previous page once the timeout is expired as shown below

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        //super.onBackPressed(); use finish instead to close activity
        finish();
        return;
    }
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    goBack();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
        }
    }, 2000);
}

public void goBack(){
     if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
         mWebView.goBack();
     } else {
         finish();
     }
}
```

Hope it helps, Goodluck

Comment: Nope it didn't work out for me, when pressed twice it does nothing and show  Plese click back again to exit and when pressed twice will exit the app. But I want to go to previous page if pressed once.

Comment: Ive made corrections, it should work now. As Ive previously stated it'll be better if there was a back button so you wont end up confusing your users between going back in the webview and finishing the activity

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isDouble = false;
private int DURATION = 1000;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isDouble) {
        finishAndRemoveTask();
        return;
    }

    isDouble = true;
    finish();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isDouble=false;                       
        }
    }, DURATION);
}
```